# Deleted route function still serves old version of EJS file in Node/express App

Tags: node.js, express

I cannot reach modified version of my resource that is a html template, index.ejs, in uri '/' in my node-express app.

I have tried clearing and disabling Safari cache, restarting node server, even completely copy all the projects files to a new project dir, start server in another port etc.

Strange is that the version of the index.ejs file my browser shows in localhost:8080/ is non-existent. I have deleted it put the new one with new content. But I cannot view the new document in the browser in the '/' path, but only in another path, say '/i', if I set in server to respond with the same template, index.ejs.

Even if I delete the route function that serves index.ejs in path '/', it still serves it! How can this happen?

What can be the cause of this?

Old route to serve index.ejs that is deleted and still works when browser visited:

```
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('index.ejs');
    });
```

New route to the modified version of the file index.ejs is not served with '/' path but only the old version of it is visible when '/' is visited. Following is the new route I have defined to be able to view the modified version of the index.ejs:

```
app.get('/i', function(req, res) {
        res.render('index.ejs');
    });
```

Comment: Please show small reproducible example of your problem so we can better help you.

Comment: My first suspicion is another middleware intercepting the request. Can you show us the entire Express application configuration code?

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred to me a few weeks ago when I was working on Node.js + Express + TS application. So apparently, I put some html files inside the `public/` directory that I marked as static using `express.static()` because I was converting them to EJS so that I can later put those ejs files inside the `views/` directory. Deleting those HTML files fixed my issue.